# Unknow Class android.os.Build.VERSION

Tags: android

I'm using the version handling and conditioning it but getting an error as:

```
Unknown Class 'android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT'
```

This is my code:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
   //TODO
}
```

Comment: Did you import the class `android.os.Build.VERSION` correctly?

Comment: I imported android.os.Build but it is unused

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: I did that and rebuild

Comment: What is your `compileSdkVersion`?

Comment: Compile SdkVerison is 25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I updated my Android Studio and other SDK Tools and now it works fine. Maybe a wrong configuration or a file change caused the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and fixed it by moving the code into the onCreate method of the activity.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Comment: @thewaywewere I think draksi provided a quality answer. It was the fix for the same error that I was getting.